# Summarise data frame by finding the percentage of a particular of occurrence of a particular variable for each unique values

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to find the percentage of sense in ore column for each unique transcript_id

```
transcript_id    ore      
A1               sense        
A1               sense        
A1               antisense      
A2               sense      
A2               antisense      
A3               sense     
A4               antisense      
A4               antisense
```

expected output

```
 transcript_id    fraction  
        A1            0.66
        A2            0.5
        A3            1
        A4            0
```

Comment: Please, use `dput` for sharing example data.

Comment: Could just do `prop.table(table(df), margin = 1)` and get the proportions for both (without any external packages)

Comment: `aggregate(ore~transcript_id, dat, FUN=function(x) sum(x=="sense")/length(x))` in base R will return the above output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% summarise(fraction = sum(ore == "sense")/n())

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  transcript_id  fraction
#         <fctr>     <dbl>
#1            A1 0.6666667
#2            A2 0.5000000
#3            A3 1.0000000
#4            A4 0.0000000
```

Which is equivalent to (if using `mean` as commented by @docendo and there are no missing values in `ore`):

```
df %>% group_by(transcript_id) %>% summarise(fraction = mean(ore == "sense"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  transcript_id  fraction
#         <fctr>     <dbl>
#1            A1 0.6666667
#2            A2 0.5000000
#3            A3 1.0000000
#4            A4 0.0000000
```